# How do I make a Pause/Play cycle button on an image slider using jQuery and make the image fade in and out smoothly and without flashing?

Tags: jquery, image

Im still very new to javascript and finding it a little hard to get my head around it.

I would like the pause/play button to be one button and cycle through when it has been clicked on.

I was also wondering how to make the image transition more smoother with the fade in and out? I've tried changing the seconds in the fadeIn and fadeOut but it doesn't seem to make much difference, so I am a little lost on what to do now. Also how do I make the image stop doing the flash in between transitions?

Thanks, Gabi.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="slider">
<img id="1" src="images/kirsty_family01.jpg">
<img id="2" src="images/kirsty_family02.jpg">
<img id="3" src="images/kirsty_family03.jpg">
<img id="4" src="images/kirsty_family04.jpg">
<img id="5" src="images/kirsty_family05.jpg">
<img id="6" src="images/kirsty_family06.jpg">
</div>
<a href="#" class="left" onClick="prev();return false;">Previous</a>
<a href="#" class="right" onClick="next();return false;">Next</a>
<a href="#" class="right" onClick="stop();return false;">Pause</a>
<a href="#" class="right" onClick="play();return false;">Play</a>
</div>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
sliderInt=1;
sliderNext=2;

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#slider>img#1").fadeIn(1000);
startSlider();
});

function startSlider(){
count = $("#slider>img").size();

loop = setInterval(function(){

    if(sliderNext>count){
        sliderNext=1;
        sliderInt=1;
        }

    $("#slider>img").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#slider>img#"+sliderNext).fadeIn(1000, function() {
    $(this).siblings().hide();
});


    sliderInt=sliderNext;
    sliderNext=sliderNext+1;

    },3000)
}


function prev(){
newSlide=sliderInt-1;
showSlide(newSlide);
}

function next(){
newSlide=sliderInt+1;
showSlide(newSlide);
}

function stop(){
    window.clearInterval(loop);
}

function play(){
newSlide=sliderInt+1;
showSlide(newSlide);
}

$('#play_toggle').bind("click",function(){
if(stop){
    play();
    $(this).html("pause");
    }else{
        video.pause();
    $(this).html("play"); }
});


function stopLoop(){
window.clearInterval(loop);
}


function showSlide(id){
stopLoop();

if(id>count){
        id=1;
        } else if(id<1){
            id=count;
            }

    $("#slider>img").fadeOut(1000);
    $("#slider>img#"+id).fadeIn(1000);

    sliderInt=id;
    sliderNext=id+1;
    startSlider();
}

$("#slider > img").hover(
     function () {
           stopLoop();
      },
      function() {
           startSlider();
           }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#play_toggle').bind("click",function(){
if(stop){
    play();
    $(this).html("pause");
    }else{
        video.pause();
    $(this).html("play"); }
});
```

These code works fine to change the texts, you need to change the on click attribute too,

```
$('#play_toggle').bind("click",function(){
    if(stop){
       play();
       $(this).html("pause");
       $(this).attr('onclick', 'stop();');
    }else{
        video.pause();
        $(this).html("play");
        $(this).attr('onclick', 'play();');
    }
```

});

BTW, I would suggest to use some plugins, instead of manual slide show..
http://bxslider.com/

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for answering, however that didn't work, do I have to change anything else in the code? I've tried using a few plugins but I wasn't happy with them so I would rather make my own image slider if possible....

Comment: change that prop to attr, i. e, `$(this).attr('onclick', 'play();');`